# Recursive function freezing, Jira Forge app

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, atlassian-forge

I am trying to do:

1. pull 50 rows from third party API
2. create payloads for issues
3. create issues (bulk)
4. back to step 1. until I pulled all rows from third party API.

Code:

```
  /**
 * Create Jira Issues
 *
 * @param configuration
 * @param assetType
 * @param allIds
 * @param findingsOffset
 */
export const createJiraIssue = async (configuration: IntegrationConfiguration, assetType: string, allIds: any, findingsOffset: number) => {

//HERE I AM GETTING 50 rows from third party API
    const findings: any = await getAllFindings(configuration.assets, 'open', assetType, findingsOffset);
    const custom_field: string = await storage.get('whvid_custom_field_id');
    let jiraIssuePayloads : any = {"issueUpdates": []};

    for (const item of findings.collection) {
        const i = findings.collection.indexOf(item);

        //Check if we can create the Jira issue
        if (!allIds.includes(item.id.toString()) && await isVulnerabilityAllowedToCreate(item)) {
//create payloads for issues
}

            
    //CREATE issues bulk
     await createIssues(jiraIssuePayloads);
 
    jiraIssuePayloads = null;
  //here I am calling same function but with new offset
    if (findings['offset'] > 0) {
        await createJiraIssue(configuration, assetType, allIds, findings['offset']);
    }
}
```

Third party API call:

```
export const getAllFindings = async (assets: [], status: string, assetType: string, startOffset: number) => {

    const findings =  await getFindingByAssetIdAndAssetType(assets, status, assetType, startOffset.toString());

    if(findings.page.totalPage !== findings.page.currentPage){
        findings.offset = startOffset + limit.FINDINGS;
    }

    return findings;

}
```

My app usually stop working after 18th call. With no error no logs anything. I am very new to JS, so maybe problem is async functions.
Any idea what can be problem?

Thank you

Comment: Try slowing down your requests. Maybe there's a limit for the API.

Comment: @ITgoldman i already tried that and it did not help, and I think this API does not have limit anyway.